# Call Flex4 function by any event happen in mx:html container in windowed application

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, externalinterface

I am working with Flex 4 windowed application. I have a mx:HTML container with location attribute like http://bla.com/**abc.html**. That **abc.html** has a html button and i want when that html button is clicked then a flex windowed application function should be called. How can i do that please guide.

Dummy Flex 4 windowed application screen shot: http://i41.tinypic.com/2u8kuxk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try , accessing flex from  javascript.

http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/air-actionscript-javascript-bridge/

or

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function addBlu(a, b) { return (a+b); }
    -->
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

And with my poor AS3 code:

```
import flash.html.HTMLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;

var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
html.load(new URLRequest("callJS.html"));
html.width = 0;
html.height = 0;
html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

addChild(html);

function onLoaded(e:Event) :void
{
  trace("result (4+8) : "+e.target.window.addBlu(4, 8));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but It is not working. It is showing error. Error is "Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime.".